# findViewById returns null in run time although the id exist in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, r.java-file

I have a class where I set ContentView of XML layout

```
setContentView(R.layout.car_layout);
```

and then setting all members:

```
    text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

    text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);

    textCar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCar);

    textId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textId);
```

everything complies, but in run time I get crash error saying that `R.id.textCar` is `null`, but that field exist for 100% and also it have an value in `R.java` file . I tried to change the name but it still returns a `null`. 
Tried to clean the project,rebuild it,deleted the `.iml` ... nothing happened.

What could be the problem? (I uses Android Studio)

Comment: Do you have same layout for multiple resolutions? Maybe this id is not present in car_layout.xml which that device is picking causing runtime error

Comment: Post your layout.car_layout,xml file